# Create kivvy text inputs/labels using a for loop

Tags: python, kivy

I have an example of my code below, where it takes in a dictionary of variables and creates text inputs based on how many variables are in the dictionary:

```
class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        layout = GridLayout(cols=4, spacing=10, size_hint_y=None)
        layout.bind(minimum_height=layout.setter('height'))

        inputsdict, equationname = EqList1.xy_labels()
        for key1, val in inputsdict.items():
            label = Label(text=val['name'] +' '+ val['unit'], size_hint_y=None)
            # id = val['name']
            input = TextInput()
            layout.add_widget(label)
            layout.add_widget(input)

        return layout
```

Is there a way to get all the design stuff into a kv file while being able to use a for loop (or some other method) to create the arbitrary number of text inputs?

Comment: Hi there, I don't think I've used Kivy before, but for the sake of clarifying your question: is there something that isn't working with your `for` loop approach?

Comment: @summea No it will work, I just want to use the kv file to clean up the python side of things. It's also easier to visualize it, atleast for me

Comment: Oh, so instead of having the `for` loop in the above code itself, you might want to put that part into a `.kv` file? If so, do you think something like [dynamic classes](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.lang.html#dynamic-classes) would work?